# MySQL Filter for at least 1 of 3 values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to learn SQL and I have got this table with the following columns:

purchase_ID: Integer
department_name: Shoes, Shirts, Trousers
item: blue shoes, red shoes, green shoes, blue trousers, red trousers, green trousers, blue shirt, red shirt, green shirt,

How do I filter for IDs that bought at least 1 pair of shoes, 1 pair of trousers and 1 pair of shirt TOGETHER?
Here is my code:

```
SELECT
purchase_id
Where department_name IN ("Shoes","Trousers","Shirts")
AND item IN (
'red shoes',
'green shoes',
'blue shoes'
AND department_name IN (
'red trousers',
'green trousers',
'blue trousers'
AND department_name IN(
'red shirts',
'green shirts',
'blue shirts'
GROUP by 1
```

Comment: Provide more information on the tables and try to write a simple mathematical logic for what you want. Then try to translate it to `SQL`. But first you have to try.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation in HAVING.